# Extract diagonal area from image

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform, interpolation, feature-extraction

I have a gray scale image of fibres in different orientations. My goal is to mark the area where the fibres have a specific angle and neglect the rest. In the future it should be an automated process with similar images but different width of the areas to mark. That's my input image with the marked area to extract:

[image: Input]

At first I removed the vertical white threads which distort the spectrum a lot. I removed them by finding outliers with thresholding and interpolating the "holes" by directional interpolation. The result is here:

[image: Threads Interpolated]

Now I did some FFT Filtering and removed all occurring orientations but the -45°, so that it looks as following:

[image: FFT Filtered]

Now it looks like an easy task to extract the "non fibre area", but I'm struggling with that. Simple thresholding isn't possible, cause the grayvalues are similar all across the image. I tried with gradient but the result isn't satisfying. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: It looks like you need to find the correct algorithm using a heuristically guided stochastic search.  In other words -- make wild-ass guesses (the stochastic part), ask yourself if they might work (the heuristic part), try them out, then keep the ones that look best (the search part).  Personally, instead of looking for what I _don't_ want and then looking for uniformity, I think I'd look for what I _do_ want, which is lines at a more or less 45 degree angle in the up-right, down-left direction.  Filter for that, and then look for lots of contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, TimWescott! The heurisitc approach was a great idea. I divided the image in rectangles and evaluated the quotient of standard deviations in +45 and -45 direction. That gave me a good division of feature and non-feature area:

[image]

Then I just did a thresholding and that was it :)

[image]

Comment: Hi Tim, any chance to read, if ony a bit of it, the code you used to clearly differentiate perpendicular 'wave fronts'?

Answer (score 2):

**1.- Input image and fix contrast**

```
A=imread('001.jpg');
```

3 layers RGB to single layer Y:

```
A1=rgb2gray(A); 

[sz1,sz2]=size(A1)  % sz1:Y  sz2:X
h1=figure(1); imshow(A1); title('input image A')
```

Choosing best contrast can be done manually with imcontrast or automatically with command imadjust

```
A2=imadjust(A1,[0/255,11/255]);

figure(2);imshow(A2);title('tune contrast A')

imcontrast(h1)
```

[image]

[image]

**2.- FFT2(A)**

```
fftA2=fft2(A2);               % image spectrum not centered
fftcA2=fftshift(fftA2);      % image spectrum centered

figure(3); imshow(log(1+abs(fftcA2)),[]); title('centered |FFT(A)|')
```

[image]

```
A3=imgradientxy(A2,'intermediate');  % sobe (default) | prewitt | central | intermediate
```

Binarizing

```
B1=A3;
B1(B1>0)=255;B1(B1<0)=0;
B1=logical(B1);
A3=B1;
figure(4);h2=imshow(A3);title('A3 binarized image')
```

[image]

Centering spectrum

```
fftA3=fft2(A3);             
fftcA3=fftshift(fftA3);      % centered spectrum

figure(5); imshow(abs(fftcA3),[]); title('centered |FFT(A)|')
```

[image]

surf(|FFT2(A)|)

```
figure(5); hs11=surf(10*log10(abs(fftcA3))); title('surf centered |FFT(A)|');hs11.EdgeColor='none'`
```

[image]

check min max mean values of |image spectrum|

```
min(abs(fftcA3(:)))
max(abs(fftcA3(:)))
mean(abs(fftcA3(:)))

% fftcA32_m=abs(fftcA3); % /mean(abs(fftcA3(:)));  % -min(abs(fftcA3/mean(abs(fftcA3(:)))));
fftcA32_m=abs(fftcA3); % /mean(abs(fftcA3(:)));
fftcA32_a=angle(fftcA3);
```

check splitting mod angle real imag and then combining keeps image

```
[fftcA32r,fftcA32i]=pol2cart(fftcA32_a,fftcA32_m);
fftcA32_2=fftcA32r+1j*fftcA32i;
A32_2=ifft2(fftcA32_2);
A32_2=real(A32_2); % ifft2 returns imaginary amounts 1e-15 

figure(6);imshow(A32_2,[])
```

[image]

The portions of spectrum that I removed didn't work

**3.- nulling FFT(A)<th1**

```
th1=500;

fftcA33_m=fftcA32_m;
fftcA33_m(fftcA33_m<th1)=0;

figure(7); ax7=gca;
hs11=surf(ax7,fftcA33_m);hs11.EdgeColor='none';title('centered |FFT(A)| small values removed');
hold(ax7,'on')
```

[image]

```
[fftcA33r,fftcA33i]=pol2cart(fftcA32_a,fftcA33_m);
fftcA33=fftcA33r+1j*fftcA33i;
A33=ifft2(fftcA33);
A33=real(A33);

figure(8);imshow(A33,[]); title('effect nulling |FFT(A)|<th1 []')
```

[image]

Now, although grey one can appreciate that there are 2 zone, one stripes at 45° (area of interest) and the larger zone at 135°.

**4.- How to find spectrum peaks**

```
[pks,locs,W,P]=findpeaks(fftcA32_m(:),'Threshold',th1/2);
[ylocs,xlocs]=ind2sub(size(fftcA32_m),locs);
plot3(ax7,xlocs,ylocs,pks,'r*')
```

[image]

```
xylocs=[xlocs ylocs]
```

Here I tried to zero single peaks (a small square around) or all peaks in each quadrant, different combinations, but no improvement.

**5.- Filtering with pattern samples
After trying different samples and filters, the smaller H1 the better**

```
H1=[0 0 1;0 1 0;1 0 0];

B2_1=imfilter(A2,H1); 
figure(9); imshow(B2_1);
```

[image]

```
B2_12=~imbinarize(B2_1);

figure(10);imshow(B2_12);hold on;title('sought area now available')
[ny,nx]=find(B2_12==1);
plot(nx,ny,'r*')

fitobj1=fit(nx,ny,'poly1') 
p1=fitobj1.p1;p2=fitobj1.p2;
plot([1 sz1],[p1+p2 p1*sz1+p2],'b','LineWidth',1.5)

plot(fitobj1,nx,ny,'g-')
```

[image]

**6.- Regression line**

```
x0=[1:1:-sz1]';
y0=(p1*x0+p2);
7.- Calculating point-to-line distances
D=[];
a=-p1;b=1;c=-p2;r=1/(a^2+b^2)^.5;
for k1=1:1:numel(nx)
    D=[D; abs(a*nx(k1)+b*ny(k1)+c)/r];
end

figure(11);hh1=histogram(D(:,1),numel(nx));grid on;title('histogram distances to regression line')
```

[image]

point-to-line distances sample

```
D([1:20])
```

**8.- Standard deviation**

```
sgm=(sum((D(:,1)-mean(D(:,1))).^2)/(numel(nx))).^.5;  
% same as
std(D(:,1));
```

`D2` 1st column is normalized distances

```
D2=[D/sgm D nx ny];

D3=sortrows(D2,1,'descend');

D3([1:20],:)
```

**95% confidence interval :** 2 sigma up 2 sigma down
removing all points outside this interval

```
D3(D3(:,1)>2,:)=[];
```

now all remaining points fall within `+2*sgm` `-2*sgm` distance to the regression line,sample

```
D3([1:20],:)
```

Removing outliers in nx ny

```
nx2=D3(:,3);ny2=D3(:,4);
```

**9.- Fitting line**

```
fitobj2=fit(nx2,ny2,'poly1'); % ,'Startpoint',[1 1],'Exclude',outL)

p12=fitobj2.p1;p22=fitobj2.p2;

figure(12);imshow(A);hold on
% [ny,nx]=find(B2_12==1);
plot(nx,ny,'r*')
hold on
plot(nx2,ny2,'go')

plot([1 sz1],[p1+p2 p1*sz1+p2],'r','LineWidth',1.5)
plot([1 sz1],[p1+p2 p1*sz1+p2]+sgm,'r','LineWidth',3)
plot([1 sz1],[p1+p2 p1*sz1+p2]-sgm,'r','LineWidth',3)
plot([1 sz1],[p12+p22 p12*sz1+p22]+sgm,'b','LineWidth',3) % corrected
pplot([1 sz1],[p12+p22 p12*sz1+p22]-sgm,'b','LineWidth',3)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this answer! I also tried a lot of fft filtering but it was never convincing. Your approach to find just a couple of values in the area and then fit a line through them is great. Unfortunately, I need to determine the borders of the area very precisely, so the 95% intervall is a good estimation but not the end. Still, from your last image I can go on now, thanks again!

Comment: Hi Till, also tried partial spectrum zeroing, some peaks, some quadrants, .. but didn't work, and I agree with you; directly manipulating the spectrum without a clear direction is not easy.

The next step is neural network processing.

Found a NN based obsolete MATLAB script for SAR (satellite imagery processing) that given a set of samples: trees, rocks, sea, oil spillage, .. the script colours imagery accordingly. But it may take me a while to upgrade it and make it fly. I will post if I fix it.

Comment: Thanks, John! I wanted to avoid using a NN, cause I found it's overkill for this task. But apprantly it's more difficult than I thought. I could also train a network instead of using a predefined one, cause we have hundreds of those images. Let me know if you fix your NN.

Comment: did TimWestcott use NN?

Comment: Maybe you didn't see that it was me who answered my own question and not Tim^^ I didn't use any kind of NN and I didn't share any code cause I didn't think that question would raise any further interest. But if you want, I can edit my answer and explain more detailed what exactly did I do.

Comment: Hi Till, thanks for mentioning it. Please, just 1 square, the standard deviation quocients +45  -45 , how do you do it? For just one square: gradient(std(image_gray_scale))?  but how do you focus on +45 or -45? many thanks

Comment: Ah I did that not very elegant^^. So actually I calculated the quotient of a square with `std(square,[],1)/std(square,[],2]`. To do that in +/-45deg, I just rotated the image first..

Comment: thanks for this comment : Efficient is Elegant